# Sobrescribir propiedad con Element.prototype

Tags: javascript, xml, prototipos

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer algo como lo siguiente:

Por ejemplo, tengo esta línea:

```
m_gridEmployee = new ASPNexusGrid(__gridEmployee.XMLDocument);
```

Esta línea es de un sistema que se hizo específicamente para Internet Explorer, entonces tengo entendido que la propiedad .XMLDocument, sólo funciona en IE, o al menos en este caso lo está haciendo.

Quisiera saber si es posible que al tratar de acceder a la propiedad XMLDocument, me regrese simplemente el valor de lo que hay en "__gridEmployee".

Algo como esto: `Element.prototype.XMLDocument = "Valor del grid"`

Al hacer esto, sí toma el valor que le estoy asignando directamente, pero no entiendo como hacer se pueda asignar lo de "__gridEmployee" o el valor del objeto que trata de acceder a esa propiedad.

Espero haberlo explicado bien.

Lo quiero hacer de esta forma ya que este caso se repite infinidad de veces y sería más sencillo así.

Agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, añade el código de cómo instancias __gridEmployee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
Element.prototype.XMLDocument = function () {
    return this;
}
```

Pero entonces se tendría que modificar al momento de pasar el valor, ya que necesita convertirse en función para que el contexto cambie, y "this" regrese el valor de __gridEmployee.

```
m_gridEmployee = new ASPNexusGrid(__gridEmployee.XMLDocument());
```

Si no se agregan los paréntesis, se pasaría la función XMLDocument como tal.